# Sub function in R not working as expected

Tags: r

```
> mysentence <- "UK is Beautiful. UK is not the part of EU since 2016"
> gsub("[0-9]*", "", mysentence)
[1] "UK is Beautiful. UK is not the part of EU since "
```

```
> mysentence <- "UK is Beautiful. UK is not the part of EU since 2016"
> sub("[0-9]*", "", mysentence)
[1] "UK is Beautiful. UK is not the part of EU since 2016"
```

```
> mysentence <- "UK is Beautiful. UK is not the part of EU since 2016"
> sub("[0-9]+", "", mysentence)
[1] "UK is Beautiful. UK is not the part of EU since "
```

Here, while using gsub, I get the expected output, but when replaced with sub, the output still has 2016 in it, which should have been removed. On performing the same command with + instead of *, the output is as expected. Why is the second example, i.e

```
sub("[0-9]*", "", mysentence)
```

not giving the same output as the other examples?

Comment: You could use `+` i.e. `sub("\\b[0-9]+", "", mysentence)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is that the `*` quantifier is **0 or more**. So `[0-9]*` will match Nothing, as well as 1 or more digits. `sub` only replaces the first match, so `sub("[0-9]*", "", mysentence)` matches 1 Nothing, right at the beginning, replaces it with `""` (also nothing), and is done.

We can see this more easily if we put a non-nothing replacement:

```
sub("[0-9]*", "HI", mysentence)
# [1] "HIUK is Beautiful. UK is not the part of EU since 2016"
```

`gsub` replaces every occurrence, and if we had a non-nothing replacement it gets pretty absurd, as it matches Nothing at every position:

```
gsub("[0-9]*", "HI", mysentence)
# [1] "HIUHIKHI HIiHIsHI HIBHIeHIaHIuHItHIiHIfHIuHIlHI.HI HIUHIKHI
#  HIiHIsHI HInHIoHItHI HItHIhHIeHI HIpHIaHIrHItHI HIoHIfHI HIEHIUHI
#  HIsHIiHInHIcHIeHI HI"
```

Using the `+` quantifier, which is **1 or more,** means that Nothing is not matched, and in this 1-match case `sub` and `gsub` behave identically, as expected:

```
gsub("[0-9]+", "HI", mysentence)
# [1] "UK is Beautiful. UK is not the part of EU since HI"

sub("[0-9]+", "HI", mysentence)
# [1] "UK is Beautiful. UK is not the part of EU since HI"
```